# Pyqtgraph ImageView not updating after QSlider value changed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I'm working on a PyQt5 + pyqtgraph user interface. The main idea is to have an image viewer that I can update using widgets from the Main Window, like sliders, line edits, buttons... By now I'm having trouble updating the image when I move the slicer. It connects to the expected functions, but the image on the ImageViewer keeps always the same (the first one). How can I solve this? I know that pyqtgraph ImageViewer can deal with 3D arrays, but in the future, I will have to add more than one viewer that will be updated by the same slider. This is the code I have:

This HDF5 file that I'm using is a (2048, 2048, 10) size array (10 uint16 images inside).

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import os, sys, h5py

class ZoomGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/GUI/ZoomGUI.ui')

        self.file_path = "recon/tomo-2048x2048x10_16bit.h5"

        #Configure slices slicer
        self.number_of_slices = self.get_number_of_slices()
        self.ui.slicesSlider.setMaximum(self.number_of_slices-1)
        self.ui.slicesSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.imageView)
        self.updateImage()

        #Add image widget
        self.ui.ImageWidget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.ui.ImageWidget.layout().addWidget(self.imv)


    def imageView(self,slice_number):
        self.imv = pg.ImageView()
        self.imagedata = self.get_image(slice_number)
        print(self.imagedata)
        self.imv.setImage(self.imagedata)

    def updateImage(self):
        actual_slice = int(self.ui.slicesSlider.value())
        self.imageView(actual_slice)

    #File related functions
    def get_image(self, slice_number):
        h5 = h5py.File(self.file_path, "r")
        data = h5["slices"][slice_number]
        h5.close()
        return(data)

    def get_number_of_slices(self):
        h5 = h5py.File(self.file_path, "r")
        size = len(h5["slices"])
        h5.close()
        return(size)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)      
    ZoomGUI = ZoomGUI()               
    ZoomGUI.ui.show()                  
    app.exec_()
```

This is the .ui file. It only has the slider and a QWidget widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1132</width>
    <height>880</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="ImageWidgetLayout">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QWidget" name="ImageWidget" native="true"/>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item row="2" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
        <property name="text">
         <string>PushButton</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="1" column="0">
       <widget class="QSlider" name="slicesSlider">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1132</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Do you realize that creating that Gui using Python-Qt as its meant to be used is as simple or simpler than using the Designer and that the code the Designer creates was meant to allow for easy porting to multiple coding languages which I am going to guess you are not doing.  So you are using black-box untouchable code to render your UI instead of coding friendly Python-Qt to render that code --- as another note if you continue using the Designer UIs you are going to run into headache after headache for everyone I have taught not to use the UIs I have taught because they had finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new ImageView that has not been added to the window so you do not see the change, the solution is to create the ImageView only once and then reuse it

```py
class ZoomGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.ui = uic.loadUi(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/GUI/ZoomGUI.ui"
        )

        self.file_path = "recon/tomo-2048x2048x10_16bit.h5"

        # Add image widget
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.ImageWidget)
        self.imv = pg.ImageView()
        lay.addWidget(self.imv)

        # Configure slices slicer
        self.number_of_slices = self.get_number_of_slices()
        self.ui.slicesSlider.setMaximum(self.number_of_slices - 1)
        self.ui.slicesSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.imageView)

        self.imageView(self.ui.slicesSlider.value())

    def imageView(self, slice_number):

        imagedata = self.get_image(slice_number)
        print(imagedata)
        self.imv.setImage(imagedata)

    def get_image(self, slice_number):
        h5 = h5py.File(self.file_path, "r")
        data = h5["slices"][slice_number]
        h5.close()
        return data

    def get_number_of_slices(self):
        h5 = h5py.File(self.file_path, "r")
        size = len(h5["slices"])
        h5.close()
        return size
```